# NUL-terminating a string by hand

Tags: c, string

Here is the method on my server-side:

```
void send_err(int socket_fd, char *msg) {
    /// To send an error message (`ERR`).

    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    printf("send_err: msg='%s' of size:%zu\n", msg, len);


    INIT_HEAD_S(head_s, ERR, len);
    send_header(socket_fd, &head_s, sizeof(cmd_header_t));
    send_msg(socket_fd, msg, len * sizeof(char));
}
```

I call the method this way: `send_err(socket_fd, "»»»»»»»»» illogical REQ request.\0");`

The socket is set up properly, and the `send_header` and `send_args` methods work fine.

On the server-side, the `printf` works just fine, but the `strlen` does not return the proper value (it should be `33`, but it's giving out `43` instead).

On the client-side, the message received is undefined: some times there are weird extra characters appearing. Apparently, manually adding a `\0` doesn't seem to actually add a NUL character at the end of my String.

How am I supposed to do this? **I want the method to not require the person to count how many characters they are sending since it's annoying to do so.**

Comment: @AlexF I've posted my (your) answer. If you feel like posting one, I'll prioritize accepting yours.

Comment: It's supposed to be spelled it `nul` (1 el) if it's `\0`, the character and`NULL`/null if it's the null pointer.

Comment: @PSkocik you mean for the title? Good comment. I changed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void send_err(int socket_fd, char *msg) {
    /// To send an error message (`ERR`).

    size_t len = strlen(msg)+1; // because `strlen` doesn't include the NUL char
    printf("send_err: msg='%s' of size:%zu\n", msg, len);


    INIT_HEAD_S(head_s, ERR, len);
    send_header(socket_fd, &head_s, sizeof(cmd_header_t));
    send_msg(socket_fd, msg, len * sizeof(char));
}
```

As [Alex F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279313/alex-f) suggested in the comments, my error was with the manipulation of `strlen`. I simply needed to add a `+1`.